# on postback get data from model

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dropdown in .NET Core MVC and condition is if value is already selected then I don't have to show the drop down but if it's not selected and saved then I have to show it and force the user to select one if he wants to save.

I was trying not to bind dropdown  by

```html
@if (Model.Input.RoleId == 0) 
{
  <div class="form-group" id="dvRole">
    <label asp-for="Input.RoleId" class="label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Input.RoleId" asp-items="@(new 
      SelectList(Model.User_Role, " ItemCode ", "ItemDisplayName "))" id="ddlRole">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
}
```

but when I am clicking on save it gives error. I am checking `model.validate` and there it throws error buz `Input.RoleId` is not having any value while post back.

Please suggest.

property is defined as

```cs
[Display(Name = "Role")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please define your role.")]
public int? RoleId { get; set; }
```

I handled it by binding the dropdown always and hiding the div using jquery but I don't think that is an optimal way to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you have decorate your `RoleId` with an attribute `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please define your role.")]`, don't set it as an optional vale `int?` at the same time:

```
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please define your role.")]
    public int? RoleId { get; set; } 
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
```

2. Avoid adding an empty value for `RoleId` dropdown list by `<option value=""></option>`.Finally, change your view as below:

```
    @if (Model.Input.RoleId == 0) 
    {
    <div class="form-group" id="dvRole">
        <label asp-for="Input.RoleId" class="label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Input.RoleId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.User_Role, "ItemCode", "ItemDisplayName"))" id="ddlRole">
        </select>
    </div>
    }
```

It works for me.

---

As a side note If you have to use the `int?` type for `RoleId`, you need to check whether the `Model.Input.RoleId` is `null` or whether it equals `0`.